# Using iMac running Ubuntu as monitor for MacMini running OSX

Tags: multiple-monitors, mac, hdmi, macosx

So, what I want to do is use my iMac (which is running Ubuntu) as a monitor for my MacMini. I am using the HDMI out on the MacMini. I have the HDMI cable being converted to MiniDisplayPort and have that going into the iMac. Is there any way I will be able to use the iMac as a monitor for the MacMini? If so, how?

Comment: This might be a more appropriate question to be asked on the Apple Stack Exchange website located [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mac os X and not Ubuntu!

Comment: @Alvar The question's title says "iMac running Ubuntu" and the body says "my iMac (which is running Ubuntu)." If you believe this nonetheless should be considered not to be about Ubuntu, please explain in detail.

Comment: @EliahKagan he want to use it as an monitor for a computer running mac os x, therefor off topic. yes the "monitor" is running Ubuntu, but how does that help the question?

Comment: @Alvar The Ubuntu system (and not merely the hardware on which it exists) may serve as the interface. To the extent to which this is a software question at all, it is about Ubuntu. I see no indication that the only solutions are pure hardware based (or even that there are any pure hardware solutions to this problem). If we do end up closing this, it should be considered for migration to [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes a migration to askDifferent would I suggest too. will the question is sort of a grey area since it covers both Ubuntu on the client side and Mac os X on the host side, so you need a tool for both.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how old the iMac is. If the iMac has Thunderbolt ports there may be a way. If the iMac does not have Thunderbolt ports then the answer is no. There is no way to use that iMac as a monitor for the Mac-Mini running Mac OSX.

You could use VNC to connect to the Mac-Mini over your internal network.